# How do I parse an array query parameter in an Ember.js controller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to parse an array query parameter in the controller

(e.g. `/info/?id=6b2c2a2cd93a437db776a21282686c39&id=c2ffb7b2970e4374a20b699105d420e4`)

So id should be an array of `[6b2c2a2cd93a437db776a21282686c39,c2ffb7b2970e4374a20b699105d420e4]`

However, Ember just sets id to be the last element in the array, it doesn't set id to the actual array.

How do I do this in Ember??

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Ember has an official documentation. It does not cover all topics and sometimes it is outdated, but for query parameters documentation is good enough. Here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/query-params/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right uri:

```
/info/?id[]=6b2c2a2cd93a437db776a21282686c39&id[]=c2ffb7b2970e4374a20b699105d420e4
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you know to do this? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: many frameworks from php to js do it like this. Unfortunately I can't find any query strings standard definition, but example for ember here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucanam/2849#/?foo[]=ray&foo[]=tiley&foo[]=test